# getting error for ambiguous symbol and need help to remove it

Tags: c++

i am getting this error which i unable to remove in visual studio 2010. i am using one third party library which uses its own definition for "string" Also visual studio's xstring file is there in the folder where it gets installed. now when i am trying to compile code i am getting following error

1>...\xyz.cpp(24): error C2872: 'string' : ambiguous symbol
1>          could be 'third party library path\string.h(31)
1>          or       'c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xstring(2063) : std::string'

compiler is not able to understand which string definition it should use. How can i remove this error in visual studi 2010. I want the code to use third party string definition.

i tried to set third party path in include directory but still i am seeing this error.
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use std::string instead of just string?

Comment: @BoBTFish "I want the code to use third party string definition." ;)

Answer (score 11):

This is an example of a *namespace clash*. You probably have in your code:

```
#include <3rdPartyString.h> // declaration of 3rd party string type
#include <string> // declaration of std::string
using namespace 3rdPartyNamespace;
using namespace std;
...
string myStr; // which string type?
```

Compiler now doesn't know which string you want to use - one from 3rd party library or STL one. You can resolve this ambiguity by prepending namespace name to the type:

```
3rdPartyNamespace::string myStr; // if you want to use string from 3rd party library
```

or

```
std::string myStr; // if you want to use STL string
```

Never place `using namespace namespace_name;` in headers but try to avoid it in source files as well. The best practice is to prepend type name as this does doesn't pollute your current namespace with the other one thus avoiding namespace clashes.

Answer (score 5):

Namespaces were invented to prevent these ambiguities. Make sure you never use `using namespace std` (that specific `using namespace` is bad practice anyway, and "`std::`" isn't that long to type) and it should be fine, just use `std::string` if you want the standard string.

```
// Without "using namespace std;"
string foo; // string from third party library used.
std::string bar; // string from standard library used.
```

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions of string are clashing with each other so the compiler doesn't know what to use so you need a way to differentiate the two and that's where namespaces come in.

You can use the namespace that your third party string uses when referring to that string as the errors you are showing implies you have `using namespace std` in your code.

Comment: Firedragon : thank you very much for quick reply. I tried using third party namespace but at that time i commented "using namespace std;" since i thought both are not needed. just after seeing you reply i added third party namespace macro and did not removed "using namespace std;" and my code got compiled successfully. dont complier get confused with having 2 namespaces?
i dont have much knowledge about namespaces so sorry if this question is silly.
again thank you for quick reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently by adding a Class Library project to a very large solution that included an in-house String library, the `using namespace System;` in the pre-generated header was causing the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

There is System.String. If not intended to use, make sure to indicate otherwise. Example System::String, or Custom::String