# How to overcome a double declaration of struct C++ in OpenCV and RTMaps?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, declaration, redefinition

I have to use a software tool called **RTMaps** (block based programming environment) for vision based real time control. I'm used to **OpenCV** and **RTMaps** supports to create my own blocks in C++, so I wrote my image processing algorithm with **Opencv**.

The problem is that in **RTMaps** the Iplimage is already defined as a data type so when I try to integrate my code in a new block I get this nasty error:

How can I overcome this issue, not to have double declaration of the same type? I need other functions/data types from the **OpenCV** lib and I cant change the **RTMaps** core.

> ```
> >c:\program files (x86)\intempora\rtmaps 4\include\maps_object_types.hpp(608): error C2011: '_IplROI' :
> 'struct' type redefinition
> 1>          D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(326) : see declaration of '_IplROI'
> 1>c:\program files (x86)\intempora\rtmaps 4\include\maps_object_types.hpp(631): error C2011: '_IplImage' :
> 'struct' type redefinition
> 1>          D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(284) : see declaration of '_IplImage'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6464): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6522): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6523): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6524): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6525): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7234): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7242): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7249): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7256): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7263): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7279): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7288): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7297): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7306): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7320): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7327): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7334): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7341): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7348): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7358): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7368): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7378): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
> ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7786): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(7787): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' :
>  ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1194): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK'
> : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1204): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1220): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1232): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1252): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK'
> : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1260): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1273): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK'
> : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1365): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1373): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK'
> : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1387): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK'
> : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winuser.h(1394): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winreg.h(65): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol
> 1>          could be 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6463) : DWORD ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>          or       'D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp(60) : ACCESS_MASK'
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(80): error C2027: use of undefined type '_IplImage'
> 1>          D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(284) : see declaration of '_IplImage'
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(80): error C2228: left of '.channelSeq' must have class/struct/union
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(81): error C2027: use of undefined type '_IplImage'
> 1>          D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(284) : see declaration of '_IplImage'
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(81): error C2228: left of '.channelSeq' must have class/struct/union
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(82): error C2027: use of undefined type '_IplImage'
> 1>          D:\OpenCV\build\include\opencv2/core/types_c.h(284) : see declaration of '_IplImage'
> 1>src\maps_cameraCalibration.cpp(82): error C2228: left of '.channelSeq' must have class/struct/union
> 1>  RailwayImageProcess.cpp
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a macro to tell RTMaps to avoid redefining the IplImage structure. In your header, you need to write your includes in the following order:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> //Or any other OpenCV header
#define __IPL_H__
#include "maps.hpp"
```

Comment: I did like this but I still get some nastier errors like:
`>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\include\winnt.h(6464): error C2872: 'ACCESS_MASK' : ambiguous symbol`

Comment: the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360375/getting-error-for-ambiguous-symbol-and-need-help-to-remove-it) is to not use `namespace` in headers

Answer (score 3):

After looking at this:
[Can't use OpenCV namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16299822/cant-use-opencv-namespace)
I think you also can use c++ headers instead of c ones, so OpenCV entities go into "cv" namespace. That should resolve name conflict.

Comment: the C++ headers are in the `opencv2` lib, in this lib it is not any more included the `Iplimage` type, only the `Mat` and there are no functions to work with `Iplimage`. Moreover, in **RTMaps** only exist the `Iplimage` data type.

Comment: An other issue, is that the **opencv** `Iplimage` is a `cv::_InputArray` but the **TRMaps** is not.

Comment: So, it was needed to merge entities rather than separate them. Anyway, I'm glad that you got solution.